# yii2 active record сложные запросы

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, activerecord

Есть таблица анкет(polls). Polls относится к одному заказу(orders) и связано с ним по полю order_id. Кроме этого у анкеты есть пару видов оценок. Эти оценки хранятся в таблице scores, где в поле poll_id указана id анкеты, в поле type указывается тип оценки, в поле score значение оценки. Заказ(orders) может быть выполнен только одним филиалом, с таблицей филиалов(filials) связь по полю filial_id. Также заказ принадлежит только одному клиенту(таблица clients), связь по полю client_id. Выводятся следующие данные по анкетам

- Типы оценок и соответствующие им значения
- Название филиала
- Дата анкеты(поле Polls.created)
- Телефон клиента(clients.phone)

С выводом общего списка анкет я справился. Использовал следующий запрос:

```
$polls = Poll::find()
    ->where(['status_id'=>7])
    ->with('scores','scoreDishes','order.client','order.filial')
    ->orderBy(['created' => SORT_DESC])
    ->all();
```

Для этого я указал связи для модели Poll:

```
public function getOrder() {
    return $this->hasOne(Order::className(), ['id' => 'order_id']);
}

public function getScores() {
    return $this->hasMany(Score::className(), ['poll_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getScoreDishes() {
    return $this->hasMany(ScoreDish::className(), ['poll_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Для модели Order:

```
public function getFilial() {
    return $this->hasOne(Filial::className(), ['id' => 'filial_id']);
}

public function getClient() {
    return $this->hasOne(Client::className(), ['id' => 'client_id']);
}
```

Но теперь проблема с фильтрацией данных. Как нужно изменить запросы, чтобы получить только те анкеты, которые относятся к заказам, которые выполнены конкретным филиалом. То есть те строки, где поле filial_id у таблицы orders равно например 2.
Структура таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE `polls` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `scores` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `poll_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `score_dishes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `poll_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dish_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `filial_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `driver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `operator_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `filials` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `crm_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Добавьте структуру в виде таблиц.

Comment: @svgrafov, добавил структуры таблиц

Comment: Добрый день. Фильтрацию делайте через поисковую модель.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - добавить heaving, что-то на подобии: heaving(['`orders`.`filial_id`' => 2]).
Можно это и в сам запрос засунуть, но нужно будет переделать на join-ы